# sql-mode doesn't work in emacs: can't send a string in a SQL to the buffer to run in database

Tags: emacs

I installed a package of vertica to enable sql running against vertica. And I could open a new window by kick off a start session command in the menu under "SQL", and then I mark a region, run the command of "sql-send-region" using M-x. it returned message in minu buffer is "Sent strings to buffer *SQL*", however in the *SQL* buffer, there is no string appended. What's the possbile reason. I have installed evil mode, even after I toggled it to edit in emacs mode, it still doesn't work.

Comment: The behaviour I'm used to when sending queries to a SQL interpreter from another buffer is that the specified query is sent to the *process*, but is not itself inserted into the buffer. That means you have one buffer for editing queries, and another buffer for seeing output (only). If you're seeing no output, make certain that your query is valid and complete, including terminating it with a semicolon (if appropriate; I have no familiarity with vertica).

Comment: that for the comment. I added ";" to the end of the sql, and then send the SQL to the buffer, now it works. But it shows the pure sql result, there is no prompt. even if I have set  :prompt-regexp "^veritcaSQL>, then what's the usage of prompt?